# Decode 3D-Secure PaRes in Python

Tags: python, decode, 3d-secure

I'm unable to find a way to decode information (PaRes) posted back from 3D-Secure ACS service.

Does someone have an idea how to decomress/decode this string?

```
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
```

I read somewhere that it can be base64 encoded - but I could not figure out how to decode it using python. Is it eventually compressed as well?

Any input welcome!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import base64
import zlib

data = base64.b64decode('eNrNWWmP4ziS/S...')
xml_data = zlib.decompress(data)
print xml_data
```